# Config website in apach2 via 192.xxx.x.x

Tags: web, apache2, router

Set up behind a router (192.168.1.1)! Able to access my website in apach2 via 192.168.1.2:8008 how do i access it when i type my ip address (from whatsmyip.org); where i want to access the webserver remotely!

Answer (score 1):

If there is only a router between your network and your ISP (the internet), then you just have to go into the configuration page of your router and forward port 8008 to 192.168.1.2. Then typing 1.2.3.4:8008 (replacing 1.2.3.4 with your external IP from whatsmyip.org) should, if there are no other devices or firewalls in place, display the webpage.

If you tell us what model your router is, we can be more specific on how to actually forward the port.